# Import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I use Eclipse Luna and turns out I have a bunch of import * cannot be resolved errors.

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
```

I cleaned the project, i remove it and import it but i have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

`BluetoothGatt` and other `Bluetooth GATT Profile apis` were added only in `Api Level 18`.

So in Project Properties -> Android - > Project Build target , select Target greater than 18.

or just edit project.properties to something like

```
target=android-20
```